# Python sympy cannot handle the inverse laplace transform successfully on expressions like " f = 3.36/(2.564549826*s+1)/s + 5/(2.2654984123*s+1)/s "

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I am carrying out inverse lapalce transform for various complicated expressions with sympy, and they usually end up with `ValueError: gamma function pole`. What can be done to aviod such error, and reach the result successfully ?

I had tried to decompose the expression by using `sympy.apart` function, and even rounded coefficients in the expression, but they all cannot guarantee the success of the code.

```
from sympy import *

s = symbols('s')
w = symbols('w', real =True)
t = symbols('t', positive = True)

f = 3.36/(2.564549826*s+1)/s +  5/(2.2654984123*s+1)/s

print(print(inverse_laplace_transform(f,s,t=100).evalf()))
```

The error information is `ValueError: gamma function pole`

Answer (score 3):

It's best to avoid using Floats in sympy but actually using Rational here means the integral hangs (takes a long time). If you use symbols instead you can get the answer quickly:

```
from sympy import *

s = symbols('s')
w = symbols('w', real =True)
t = symbols('t', positive = True)

a, b, c = symbols('a, b, c', real=True)

f = a/(b*s+1)/s +  5/(c*s+1)/s

pprint(f)
pprint(inverse_laplace_transform(f,s,t=100))
```

That gives

```
     a             5     
─────────── + ───────────
s⋅(b⋅s + 1)   s⋅(c⋅s + 1)
       -100           -100 
       ─────          ─────
         b              c  
a - a⋅ℯ      + 5 - 5⋅ℯ
```

You can the substitute to get the answer you want:

```
In [22]: ilt = inverse_laplace_transform(f,s,t=100)                                                                               

In [23]: ilt.subs({a: 3.36, b:2.564549826, c:2.2654984123})                                                                       
Out[23]: 8.36000000000000
```

Comment: Yes, finally I tried to decompose the expression into the simplest form and it works well.